# Findbugs non-transient non-serializable instance field

Tags: serialization, findbugs

While running the code through FindBugs to pick up smelly bits I am getting

**Bug: Class com.MyClass defines non-transient non-serializable instance field someSet
Pattern id: SE_BAD_FIELD, type: Se, category: BAD_PRACTICE**

I know set does not implement serialization but HashSet does and thats why it is being initialized then and there .I thought this was the good practice :( but apparently not

```
public class Myclass extends 
{ 
   @Transient
   private Set<String> someSet = new HashSet<String>();

        ...........
}
```

Any help would be great . Low level warning but would love to know why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, FindBugs isn't smart enough to recognize that the field that is defined as Set is actually a HashSet. It's a shortcoming of findbugs. You should add an issue here http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=96405&atid=614693